# How to deploy my outlook addin on AppSource for public?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have developed an outlook addin for appointment setting. The addin directly put meeting timings in the emails for appointment sharing. The plugin is running well on localhost and now I wish to deploy it to AppSource so that general users can use it on web-outlook as well as desktop.

In the addin I am accessing a web component from another website in an iframe. Also I am using OAuth of my appointment setting company. Please suggest me the steps to proceed. Also will I have to host my addin to some other domain and then run on outlook? Please help me out.

Comment: For add-in publish to AppSource,, please refer this doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-appsource-via-partner-center. For other Deploy and publish methods, refer- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I have seen these docs but am not getting sure that do i have to just upload the manifest and my files on appsource or I have to run my app on some other servers and then use that domain app domain in my mainfest.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Also I am trying to fetch data from a graphql api which is not getting the response due to cors issue. What url (of my addin ) should i set on my backend server to avoid this problem?

Comment: Please someone look into this issue and help me out to resolve . I have using apollo-client to set cookie in my request but there is a issue due to cors. Please tell me what domain to use for that?? @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT

Comment: Addin is hosted by developer and same url is given in Add-in manifest. You only need need to upload Addin manifest to AppSource. If your backend server is on different domain then in manifest specify the domain under AppDomains- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/appdomains